# async i/o and process results as they become available

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await

I has a simple console app where I want to call many Urls in a loop and put the result in a database table. I am using .Net 4.5 and using async i/o to fetch the URL data. Here is a simplified version of what I am doing. All methods are async except for the database operation. Do you guys see any issues with this? Are there better ways of optimizing?

```
   private async Task Run(){
        var items = repo.GetItems(); // sync method to get list from database
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        // add each call to task list and process result as it becomes available 
        // rather than waiting for all downloads
        foreach(Item item in items){
            tasks.Add(GetFromWeb(item.url).ContinueWith(response => { AddToDatabase(response.Result);}));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // wait for all tasks to complete.
    }

    private async Task<string> GetFromWeb(url) {
       HttpResponseMessage response = await GetAsync(url);
       return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    private void AddToDatabase(string item){
        // add data to database.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is acceptable. But you should check out [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx), which allows you to set up a dataflow "mesh" (or "pipeline") and then shove the data through it.

For a problem this simple, Dataflow won't really add much other than getting rid of the `ContinueWith` (I always find manual continuations awkward). But if you plan to add more steps or change your data flow in the future, Dataflow should be something you consider.

Comment: ReactiveExtensions is also a pretty good way to do it, assuming you like Linq, which given your example code, you probably don't.

Comment: @Stephen, I am not expecting any changes to the data flow. Is there any benefit to doing this inside the "add" method in the foreach loop?  Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            var response = await GetFromWeb(url);
                            AddToDatabase(response);
       })

Comment: @Aron, i assume you are hinting towards the foreach loop instead of a Linq statement? I am doing some other processing inside hence that usage.

Comment: @Aron: Good point. Rx is also a good solution whenever you're dealing with sequences of tasks.

Comment: @dotnetster in that case you might like the ReactiveExtensions due to the .Do() extension.

Comment: @dotnetster: Yes, there is a minor benefit to using `await` instead of `Result`: the exception (if any) is not wrapped in an `AggregateException` if you use `await`. So your error handling code can look more natural (if you need to catch a specific exception type).

Comment: @StephenCleary In my opinion the largest advantage of using await rather than Result is due to threading and possible deadlocks. When using Task,Factory.FromAsync(), the Task Factory will schedule the callback on the calling thread, which would be waiting for the .Result to unblock, which would unblock once the calling thread is free....>_<

Comment: @Aron: Yes, in the general case I recommend `await` instead of `Result` for that reason. But in this particular case `Result` would never block since it is only called from `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is pretty much correct, with just two minor mistakes (both of which cause compiler errors).  First, you don't call `ContinueWith` on the result of `List.Add`, you need call continue with on the task and then add the continuation to your list, this is solved by just moving a parenthesis.  You also need to call `Result` on the `reponse` `Task`.

Here is the section with the two minor changes:

```
tasks.Add(GetFromWeb(item.url)
    .ContinueWith(response => { AddToDatabase(response.Result);}));
```

Another option is to leverage a method that takes a sequence of tasks and orders them by the order that they are completed.  Here is my implementation of such a method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Task<T>> Order<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var taskList = tasks.ToList();

    var taskSources = new BlockingCollection<TaskCompletionSource<T>>();

    var taskSourceList = new List<TaskCompletionSource<T>>(taskList.Count);
    foreach (var task in taskList)
    {
        var newSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        taskSources.Add(newSource);
        taskSourceList.Add(newSource);

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var source = taskSources.Take();

            if (t.IsCanceled)
                source.TrySetCanceled();
            else if (t.IsFaulted)
                source.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
            else if (t.IsCompleted)
                source.TrySetResult(t.Result);
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    return taskSourceList.Select(tcs => tcs.Task);
}
```

Using this your code can become:

```
private async Task Run()
{
    IEnumerable<Item> items = repo.GetItems(); // sync method to get list from database

    foreach (var task in items.Select(item => GetFromWeb(item.url))
        .Order())
    {
        await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        AddToDatabase(task.Result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Corrected the compile errors. I just typed this in the question box hence the errors.

Comment: although come to think of it that looks suspiciously like an implementation of the IObservable pattern....

Comment: @Aron Yeah, you can logically think of an observable as an infinite sequence of tasks.  It's actually slightly more powerful the way it's implemented over an `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`, but but that power isn't needed in this case.

Comment: @Servy actually no. Observables aren't an infinite sequence of tasks, in the same way IEnumerables aren't an infinite sequence of T. The main difference between them is that IEnumerables are blocking, whilst Observables are non-blocking. What you have done is put non-blocking elements (Tasks) into a blocking collection. The downside is that you have a thread that is blocking/sleeping (due to the BlockingCollection<T>.

Comment: @Aron Well, instead of infinite I suppose it would be more correct to say "unknown".

Answer (score 0):

Just though I'd throw in my hat as well with the Rx solution

```
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
private Task Run()
{
    var fromWebObservable = from item in repo.GetItems.ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
                            select GetFromWeb(item.url);

    fromWebObservable
                    .Select(async x => await x)
        .Do(AddToDatabase)
        .ToTask();

}
```

Comment: Looks interesting. I will take a look.